# AWS Amplify CDK Cognito Identity Pool creation error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk, aws-amplify

This is my cdk script,

```
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import * as codecommit from "@aws-cdk/aws-codecommit";
import * as amplify from "@aws-cdk/aws-amplify";
import * as cognito from "@aws-cdk/aws-cognito";
import * as iam from "@aws-cdk/aws-iam";

export class CdkdeployStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // Part 1  - Connect to Code Commit Repository
    const codecommitRepo = codecommit.Repository.fromRepositoryName(
      this,
      "reactamplifyfullstackcdk",
      "react-amplify-fullstack"
    );

    // Part 2 - Creation of the Amplify Application
    const amplifyApp = new amplify.App(this, "reactamplifyfullstack", {
      sourceCodeProvider: new amplify.CodeCommitSourceCodeProvider({
        repository: codecommitRepo,
      }),
    });
    const devBranch = amplifyApp.addBranch("dev");
    //const qaBranch = amplifyApp.addBranch("qa");
    //const stageBranch = amplifyApp.addBranch("stage");

    // Creation of new Cognito UserPool
    const userPool = new cognito.UserPool(
      this,
      "raf-userpool", 
      {
        userPoolName: "reactamplifyfullstack_userpool",
        selfSignUpEnabled: true,
        autoVerify: {
          email: true
        },
        signInAliases: {
          email: true
        }
      }
      );

      const cfnUserPool = userPool.node.defaultChild as cognito.CfnUserPool;
      cfnUserPool.policies = {
        passwordPolicy: {
          minimumLength: 8,
          requireUppercase: true
        }
      };

    //Creation of new Userpool client
    const userPoolClient = new cognito.UserPoolClient(
      this,
      "reactamplifyfullstack_userpoolClient",
      {
        generateSecret: false,
        userPool: userPool,
        userPoolClientName: "reactamplifyfullstack_userpool_client_web"
      }
    );

    //Creation of new Identity Pool
    const identityPool = new cognito.CfnIdentityPool(
      this,
      "reactamplifyfullstack_identitypool",
      {
        allowUnauthenticatedIdentities: false,
        cognitoIdentityProviders: [{
          clientId: userPoolClient.userPoolClientId,
          providerName: userPool.userPoolProviderName
        }]
      }
    );

    //Creation of new Authenticated Role for Identity Pool
    const authenticatedRole = new iam.Role(
      this,
      "reactamplifyfullstack_auth_role",
      {
        assumedBy: new iam.FederatedPrincipal('cognit-identity.anazonaws.com', {
          "StringEquals": {'cognit-identity.anazonaws.com:aud': identityPool.ref },
          "ForAnyValue:StringLike": { 'cognit-identity.anazonaws.com:amr': "authenticated"},
        }, "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"),
      }
    );
    //Add Policy to the IAM role
    authenticatedRole.addToPolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({
      effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
      actions: [
        "mobileanalytics:*",
        "cognito-sync:*",
        "cognito-identity:*"
      ],
      resources: ['*']
    }));

    //Set Default policy
    const defaultPolicy = new cognito.CfnIdentityPoolRoleAttachment(this, "DefaultValid", {
      identityPoolId: identityPool.ref,
      roles: {
        "authenticated": authenticatedRole.roleArn
     }
    });

    //CDK output
    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'aws_project_region', { value: 'ap-south-1'});
    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'aws_cognito_identity_pool_id', { value: identityPool.ref });
    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'aws_cognito_region', { value: 'ap-south-1' });
    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'aws_user_pools_id', { value: userPool.userPoolId });
    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'aws_user_pools_web_client_id', { value: 
userPoolClient.userPoolClientId });
    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'oauth', { value: '{}' });
  }
}
```

When I am trying build,

```
npm run build
```

Showing the following error,

***> cdkdeploy@0.1.0 build

> tsc
> lib/cdkdeploy-stack.ts:57:7 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Construct'.
> Type 'CdkdeployStack' is not assignable to type 'Construct'.
> Types of property 'node' are incompatible.
> Property 'addValidation' is missing in type 'import("/home/crypto/react/react-amplify-fullstack/cdkdeploy/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/construct-compat").ConstructNode' but required in type 'import("/home/crypto/react/react-amplify-fullstack/cdkdeploy/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-cognito/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/construct-compat").ConstructNode'.
> 57       this,
> ~~~~
> node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-cognito/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/construct-compat.d.ts:439:5
> 439     addValidation(validation: constructs.IValidation): void;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 'addValidation' is declared here.
> lib/cdkdeploy-stack.ts:91:69 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Construct'.
> 91     const defaultPolicy = new cognito.CfnIdentityPoolRoleAttachment(this, "DefaultValid", {
> ~~~~
> Found 2 errors.
> npm ERR! code 2
> npm ERR! path /home/crypto/react/react-amplify-fullstack/cdkdeploy
> npm ERR! command failed
> npm ERR! command sh -c tsc
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /home/crypto/.npm/_logs/2021-02-24T08_34_57_019Z-debug.log***

Please help me tosolve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you confirm that all of your CDK-related libraries are of the same version?

Answer (score 0):

Your authrole strings have some typos

```
const authenticatedRole = new iam.Role(this, `hd-management-auth-role-${customProps.environment}`, {
        assumedBy: new iam.FederatedPrincipal(
            'cognit-identity.amazonaws.com',
            {
                'StringEquals': { 'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud': identityPool.ref },
                'ForAnyValue:StringLike': { 'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr': 'authenticated' },
            },
            'sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity'
        ),
    });
```